# Remove html tag from a string using jQquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove an HTML tag from string for example remove div,p,br,...

I'm trying to do this:

```
var mystring = "<div><p>this</p><p>is</p><p>my</p><p>text</p><p>sample</p><p> </p><p> </p></div>"

var html3 = $(mystring).text();
```

but the result is:

```
"thisismytextsample  "
```

How can do it like : "this is my text sample"

Comment: He wants the words to be spaced

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/asdasdasdas/shE58/22/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qn3gv2u8/

Comment: @EoiFirst correct!  Sorry, didn't read properly :-(

Comment: may be try to use trim method and write simple regexp replacing spaces with one whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace function :

```
var mystring="<div><p>this</p><p>is</p><p>my</p><p>text</p></div>"
var stripped = mystring.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig," "); // this is my text
```

source : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/

Comment: This causes the same result like `"thisismytextsample  "`

Answer (score 4):

You can get all p tag text in array and then join them with spaces:

```
$(mystring).find('p').map(function() {
   return $(this).text();
}).toArray().join(' '));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/manantwar/hsb2yymd/)**

Comment: thanks for your answer.this solution not work on a<div>b</div><div>c</div><div>d</div><div>

Answer (score 1):

Try this using regular expression

```
var mystring="<div><p>this</p><p>is</p><p>my</p><p>text</p><p>sample</p><p> </p><p> </p></div>"


function RemoveHTMLTags(string1) {
            var regX = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
            var html = string1;
            return html.replace(regX, " ");
        }


var res = RemoveHTMLTags(mystring);

alert(res);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0f7na54j/)

Comment: thanks for your answer.this solution not work on a<div>b</div><div>c</div><div>d</div><div>